# Absolute minimum definition

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider a function $f:\mathbb{R^3}\to \mathbb{R}$ which has an absolute minimum at a point $a$, then is it right to say that  $f(a)<f(x),\forall x \neq a$?

Comment: This really is a matter of convention, but I think the most common definition would make this false. For example, I think most people would say that a constant function attains its absolute minimum at all points. If you have a textbook you're working out of, you should consult it to see how it defined "absolute minimum"!

Comment: Agree with @diracdeltafunk that the more usual convention would be $f(a) \leq f(x)$ (non-strict inequality). But some authors may disagree!